# Why is my NSDate mock resulting in failed calls to [NSProxy methodSignatureForSelector:]?

Tags: objective-c, mocking

I'm trying to establish a pattern where I mock class methods of objects I don't own by creating a "fake" version of the class, then swizzling the orignal version to call the "fake" version's class methods and having the fake class call instance methods on a shared object which is itself mocked.

For example:

```
@interface FakeNSURLConnection : NSURLConnection
+ (void)enableMock:(id)mock;
+ (void)disableMock;
- (NSURLConnection *)connectionWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id<NSURLConnectionDelegate>)delegate;
- (BOOL)canHandleRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;
@end
@implementation FakeNSURLConnection
...
+ (NSURLConnection *)connectionWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id<NSURLConnectionDelegate>)delegate {
     return [FakeNSURLConnection.sharedInstance connectionWithRequest:request delegate:delegate];
}
- (NSURLConnection *)connectionWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id<NSURLConnectionDelegate>)delegate { return nil; }

+ (BOOL)canHandleRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request { return [FakeNSURLConnection.sharedInstance canHandleRequest:request]; }
- (BOOL)canHandleRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request { return NO; }
@end
```

What happens is that my enable mock swaps the class methods of NSURLConnection and FakeNSURLConnection and make the "sharedInstance" a mock of FakeNSURLConnection. In this way, when my mock is enabled a call like `[NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:request]` will be directed to my mock method.

This gets a little trickier with NSDate, I think because it is an "abstract" class that does toll-free bridging, but I'm not sure. I thought I could get maximum benefit out of this model by having my Fake class return real values if I wanted to partially mock an object. So we have something like this:

```
@interface FakeNSDate : NSDate
...
- (id)date;
- (id)dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds sinceDate:(NSDate *)date;
- (id)dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)seconds;
- (id)dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSTimeInterval)seconds;
- (id)dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:(NSTimeInterval)seconds;
- (id)distantFuture;
- (id)distantPast;
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate;
@end
@implementation FakeNSDate
...
+ (id)date { return [FakeNSDate.sharedInstance date]; }
- (id)date { return [[NSDate alloc] init]; }
...
@end
```

Not that I am not swizzling alloc, in fact I'm only swizzling the publicly available class methods as listed in the API for NSDate.

I'm using this code:

```
_baseDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-1.0 * 90.0 * 60.0];
_nsDateMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[FakeNSDate sharedInstance]];
NSLog(@"_nsDateMock %@", [_nsDateMock class]);
[FakeNSDate enableMock:_nsDateMock];
[[[_nsDateMock stub] andReturn:_baseDate] date];
NSLog(@"DATE: %@", [NSDate date]);
```

This code executes properly (the date reports being 1.5 hours ago) but I get an error that pops up: `[NSProxy methodSignatureForSelector:] called!`

Is the issue something I'm doing or something that partialMockForObject does? This pattern I'm using seems very helpful -- I'd hate to think it's a dead end.

Comment: I changed FakeNSDate to inherit from NSObject and the problem seems to have gone away, though it did not go away immediately -- possible there was some compiled code that needed to be cleared?

Comment: I changed FakeNSDate back to inherit from the NSDate, cleaned, and the problem is still gone. I believe I've completely reverted my code, in fact, and don't see this error anymore. Very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did two things to make my problems go away:

```
_nsDateMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[FakeNSDate sharedInstance]];
```

I must not have been unsetting this correctly and, I think, re-partial-mocking and already partial-mocked object. I changed it to just alloc a new object:

```
_nsDateMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[[FakeNSDate alloc] init]];
```

I also switched to using [the latest code off of github](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock).

Comment: All very strange an inconsistent, but I can't rule out build relics. The other error I ended up seeing and resolving (I hope?) was @"Ended up in subclass forwarder for %@ with unstubbed method %@" as an FYI to anyone have weird issues like this.